# Codename One Storage

Tags: codenameone

After failing to get sqlite to work with my solution I have decided to give the storage class a try. I have followed the instructions here: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---store-data-to-persistent-storage-storageexternalization.html and have managed to get my data into persistent storage ... I now have the following questions:

1] How do I search for a particular key to see if it exists, and then warn the user that it already exists and to decide if they wish to overwrite the existing value or not?

2] How do I update the value of a particular key if the user decides to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asking a separate question about SQLite explaining what didn't work for you as it sounds like you are looking for more of a database API than a storage API.

Storage is just a simple file system. You don't have such API's. You can load the data and loop through it using Java code then compare keys.